# Pass wordpress global variable data to localize_script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables

In my template file: `product-list-section.php` I loop through my products and add data to a global variable:

```
global $product_filter_data;
$product_filter_data = array();

// Loop products, grab specific pieces of data and add to $product_filter_data array.
$product_information_system_type = $product_information['product_information_filters']['system_type']['value'];

// Add to $product_filter_data
if( !empty( $product_information_system_type ) ) {
    $product_filter_data[] = $product_information_system_type;
}
```

If I were to var_dump the `$product_filter_data` at this point, it shows data as expected.

```
/template-parts/product-list-section.php:374:
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'system_type__ac_ups' (length=19)
  1 => string 'input__ac_1_phase' (length=17)
  2 => string 'output__ac_3_phase' (length=18)
  3 => string 'technology__thyristor_based' (length=27)
  4 => string 'battery_voltage_max__720' (length=24)
  5 => string 'capacity__900' (length=13)
  6 => string 'market_industry__oil_and_gas' (length=28)
```

Now in my setup.php file, I want to pass that data to `wp_localize_script`.

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    global $product_filter_data;
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'product_filter_data', array('php_product_filter_data' => $product_filter_data));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

```
global $product_filter_data;
var_dump($product_filter_data);

NULL
```

However when I var_dump the variable at this point, it's `NULL`:
`/app/public/wp-content/themes/testtheme/functions/setup.php:22:null`

I'm just unsure why it's NULL. I need to pass that data to JS.

Comment: I think it's because of the order. wp_enqueue_scripts runs before your template, and is therefore empty at that moment of the page load cycle.

Comment: As @Tami said, `wp_enqueue_scripts` is going to run before your template file. You need to use [AJAX to get the data for JS](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#user-contributed-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Your `wp_enqueue_scripts` is probably running before your `global $product_filter_data;`is assigned any data. You need to find a hook that runs before `wp_enqueue_scripts` but the data you are assigning to it is also available.

I usually use [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or [wp](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) for these kind of scenarios.